# CSS Help : Making content block expand to nearly full page

Tags: html, css

a very very beginner programming need help!

I am trying to expand the block content to nearly full page on mobile. Any suggestion?

CODE : https://www.w3docs.com/tools/editor/5789

WHAT I WANT.. [expand this block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCAHd.png)

Comment: Set width and height both to 100% in css

Comment: After I set both width and height, the block is expand to full page but element inside still the same. What I want is element inside also expand too. Thanks for answer @ShivamShukla :)

Comment: Set element width height also in "%" not in "px".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I changed height of  input[type=text] into 100% It getting smaller lol @ShivamShukla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Shivam this CSS:

```
  .main-block {
  max-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  background: #ebebeb; 
  }
```

Gave this result:
[image]

Isn't that what you are looking for?